# how many rows have different value

Tags: sql

Given a table events

```
sensor_id | event_type | value  | time 
----------+------------+--------+------------
2         |2           | 3.45   | 2014-02 (...)
2         |4           | (...)  | (...)
2         |2           | (...)  | (...)
3         |2           | (...)  | (...)
2         |3           | (...)  | (...)
```

Write an SQL query that returns a set of all sensors_id with the number of different event_types registered by each of them, ORDER BY sensor_id ASC

Query should return the following rowset

```
sensor_id | type 
----------+------------
2         |3          
3         |1
```

The names of the columns in the rowest don't matter, but their order does

My query:

```
SELECT 
    sensor_id, COUNT(*) AS `types` 
FROM 
    `events` 
GROUP BY 
    sensor_id 
ORDER BY 
    sensor_id ASC
```

And result:

```
sensor_id | types 
----------+------------
2         |4            <= error
3         |1
```

Answer (score 1):

use distinct event_Type inside count

```
SELECT 
    sensor_id, COUNT(distinct event_type) AS `types` 
FROM 
    `events` 
GROUP BY 
    sensor_id 
ORDER BY 
    sensor_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function:

```
select distinct sensor_id, types from (
SELECT 
    sensor_id, COUNT(distinct event_type) over(partition by sensor_id) AS `types` 
FROM 
    `events` ) X
ORDER BY 
    sensor_id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT sensor_id, COUNT(DISTINCT event_type) as type
FROM #tbltemp
GROUP BY sensor_id
ORDER BY sensor_id
```

If you do not include count distinct value it will count no 2 two times (2,2,3,4).
If you put distinct it will count as (2,3,4) only.

[image]